# Terraform parent directory uploads issue

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

When using running terraform in remote execution mode, terraform uploads the content of the configuration directory to terraform cloud. In my case, the content of the `infrastructure` directory gets uploaded:

```
functions
  function-a.zip
  function-b.zip
  ...
infrastructure
  main.tf
  ...
```

I have some terraform modules inside the `infrastructure` folder that are referencing binary files (zip files) that live outside the terraform config directory. These are build artifacts that are created prior to executing terraform. The issue is that those zip files are not copied over when executing terraform remotely which obviously causes some errors.

Is there a way to ensure that my zip files get uploaded to terraform cloud *without* having to put them inside the config directory?

Comment: Have you tried to use a symlink so that the zip files are still shown in the terraform config directory & uploaded?

Comment: Great idea, will try just that

Comment: It did the trick, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@paulg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3165785/paulg), I was able to selectively upload my function artifacts using a symlink.

Here's what my new folder structure looks like:

```
functions
  function-a.zip
  function-b.zip
  ...
infrastructure
  artifacts
    functions (symlink to ../../functions)
  main.tf
  ...
```

The only thing I needed to do after that was to adjust my modules to reference my function artifacts through the symlink.